# Disk Always shows 100% and inaccessible after certain time

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10-upgrade

It shows something like this:

[image: screenshot]

Checkdisk shows that no problem found.

the SMART status according to SPECCY is ok:

[image: smart status]

is there any possible cause why this happened?
This only happened after I upgrade to windows 10 anniversary edition.

EDIT 1: sometimes it goes back to normal again after few minutes, but mostly don't (and i have to reset the laptop)

EDIT 2: i have checked using my friend's hddregenerator, there are no bad sector

Comment: Take a look at this software http://www.hirensbootcd.org/

Comment: have you checked resource monitor to see what process is using all the disk time? (probably will get some useless info like "system", but worth a check)

Comment: Did you check in your event log? Got any Event ID 129?

Comment: An error like this is unlikely to be related to mechanical failure. It's most likely a firmware issue with advanced SATA features. It's a known issue with the Redstone Update IIRC.

Comment: @vembutech, yes, there's a lot of 129: storahci warning "Reset to device, \Device\RaidPort0, was issued.", also a lot of 153 disk warning "The IO operation at logical block address 0x8d58a78 for Disk 2 (PDO name: \Device\00000034) was retried.", even when there's no bad sector

Answer (score 1):

Some work around was given in [Microsoft support forum](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/3083595). This might help you try this.

Symptoms:

Task Manager shows the disk to be at 100% utilization despite a light or no workload, and the system may experience lag or become unresponsive. In addition, the system event log contains numerous events with Event ID 129, which represent resets of the disk controller.

Cause:

While device resets can be caused by a varying number of factors, we are aware of issues with some Advanced Host Controller Interface PCI-Express(AHCI PCIe) models that causes these symptoms in Windows 10 when running with the inbox StorAHCI.sys driver. Due to a firmware bug, the Solid-state drive (SSD) does not properly complete input/output when Message Signaled Interrupt (MSI) mode is enabled. As a result, the Windows storage stack attempts to reset the device after waiting on unresponsive reads or writes for a period of time.

Resolution:

MSI mode can be disabled for specific devices via the registry:

```
1. Identify if you are running the inbox AHCI driver (StorAHCI.sys):

    1. Open a command prompt with administrator privileges. Then type the following command in the command prompt window and hit Enter: devmgmt.msc

    2. Under IDE ATA/ATAPI Controllers right-click on the AHCI controller node and select Properties. This node is usually called “Standard SATA AHCI Controller.”

    3. Navigate to the driver tab and click Driver Details.

    4. If you see “StorAHCI.sys” in the list, you are running the inbox driver.



2. Disable MSI for the controller in the registry:

    1. In the same properties window opened in step 1.2, navigate to the Details tab and select Device instance path from the Property drop-down menu. Note this path.

    2. Open the registry editor by typing regedit in the previously opened command prompt.

    3. Navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI\ <AHCI Controller>\Device Parameters\Interrupt Management\MessageSignaledInterruptProperties, where <AHCI Controller> refers to the device instance path you noted in step 2.1. 

    4. Change the value of the MSISupported key from “1” to “0”.

    5. If you don’t know which controller your boot device is attached to, repeat steps 2.1 through 2.4 for all AHCI controllers found under 1.2.



3. Reboot the machine.
```

Comment: i'm currently using `intel(R) 8 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Driver`, so I could not confirm if this work or not. (I install them yesterday)